# Moving resources between azure subscriptions

Tags: powershell, azure

I set up an area in Azure that contains a cloud service, storage accounts, and a webapp. I need to move that to a separate subscription.

I know how to do that but my question is, is there an order that I need to follow when moving all the resources?

When I go directly to the cloud service and click `Move to a new subscription` it tells me it can't do that because it's a classic service. I'm guessing it's because I have a classic storage account under that service along with a RM storage account as well so I need to move those first?

Comment: Could you please post your error message here? It is useful for identify the cause of this issue.

Comment: Turns out that Cloud Services are classic and therefore cannot be moved from one subscription to another. I had to delete the cloud service from the old subscription and re-create it in another subscription.